# How to replace content of grid cell in SWT GridLayout?

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout

I need to replace content of grid cell after button click. For example: there is Label and I need to replace it with Text. Is it possible with GridLayout? I need to use SWT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply dispose the `Label` and put a new `Text` in its place.  `GridLayout` uses the z-order of children to determine the location in the grid, so you'll need to use the `moveAbove()` and `moveBelow()` on the `Text` in order to get it in the correct location.  Then call `layout()` on the parent.  For example:

```
Text text = new Text(label.getParent(), SWT.BORDER);
text.moveAbove(label);
label.dispose();
text.getParent().layout();
```

Here's a simple widget that illustrates exactly what I mean:

```
public class ReplaceWidgetComposite
    extends Composite
{
    private Label label;
    private Text text;
    private Button button;

    public ReplaceWidgetComposite(Composite parent, int style)
    {
        super(parent, style);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        label = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("This is a label!");

        button = new Button(this, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Press me to change");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
            {
                text = new Text(ReplaceWidgetComposite.this, SWT.BORDER);
                text.setText("Now it's a text!");
                text.moveAbove(label);
                label.dispose();
                button.dispose();
                ReplaceWidgetComposite.this.layout(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. This code causes insertion of Text cell after label, but I wanted to replace label. dispose() somehow doesn't remove label from grid because it's still visible.

Comment: Disposing a widget should remove it from its parent.  Try calling `parent.layout(true)`.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work like this. I have shell.layout(true); and I know it works because Text is inserted and I see it, but label is still visible. Did you use it somewhere and it worked correctly?

Comment: Strange.  I do it frequently and it works fine.  Can you post your code?

Comment: I would not dispose things. I think it could be better to hide them, by calling 'setVisible(false)'. At least if You are not sure about not using them again. Am I wrong?
And, aswering alhcr, it should be always good to hide element before dispose, as i believe.